# How to call varying urls in Magento

Tags: php, magento, url, foreach

What I have in my Mage site is:

```
echo "<div class='block-content'><ul>";
    foreach($listeditems as $optionId => $value) {
        echo "<li class='item'><a href=".Mage::getURL()."catalogsearch/result/?item=".$optionId.">" . $value . "</a></li>";
    }
echo "</ul></div>";
```

But I want it to echo the matching URL instead of a list of search result items.

Comment: your question is a unclear. and where is $optionId  defined?

Comment: foreach($valuesCollection as $value) {
    $listeditems[$value->getOptionId()] = $value->getValue();
   }

Comment: What is the "matching url" in your case,please mention clearly so that we could help.

Comment: Can you add more of your code?  Where is $listeditems coming from?

Comment: Every matching url should be with the same name as the listeditem.

Comment: $valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getData('attribute_id'))->setStoreFilter(0, false);
 $listeditemss = array();            
   foreach($valuesCollection as $value) {
    $listeditems[$value->getOptionId()] = $value->getValue();
   }

Comment: @Dani, rather than positing code via comment, please consider editing your question and adding that code in.

Comment: catalogsearch/result/?item  this url patterm is not work.it should be not work in default mmagento